# How to find the index of blank items in Array A and push them into the same index in Array B?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,null,4,null]
var arr2 = ["John","Adam","Barry"]
```

I need to find a way of finding the indices of ALL of the nulls in arr1 and push them into the same index in arr2. So it should look like this:

```
var arr3 = ["John","Adam",null,"Barry",null]
```

I'm using the Google Apps Script so am stuck with ES5 I'm afraid. 
I've already tried .map() and indexOf() over arr1 to find the indices but couldn't figure out a way of getting all of the null's index, just the first one.

The position of the nulls will change so I'm looking for a dynamic solution if possible. Thanks!

Comment: You need to do it one-by-one from left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `splice()` in a `forEach`-loop:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,null,4,null]
var arr2 = ["John","Adam","Barry"]
const arr3 = arr2.slice();

arr1.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (e === null) arr3.splice(i, 0, null);
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through array 1 and splice the nulls into array 2

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (!arr1[i] === null) {
    arr2 = arr2.splice(i,0,null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is clone `arr2` using `slice` as to not mutate the original array. Call this clone `arr3`. Then loop through `arr1`, if the element is `null`, add the element to `arr3` at that element's index using `splice`. I am `console.log`ging both `arr2` and `arr3` to show the original array is not mutated.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, null, 4, null]
var arr2 = ["John", "Adam", "Barry"]

mushArrays = () => {
  var arr3 = arr2.slice();
  arr1.forEach((x, i) => {
    if (x===null) {
      arr3.splice(i, 0, x);
    }
  })

  console.log(arr2)
  console.log(arr3)

}

mushArrays()
```

Comment: the (!x) will also return empty strings and zeros